# make href call a method in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, anchor, href

I would like to make the href attribute of my anchor tag to call a method instead of going to some url. I know that in plain js I can do this:

```
..href={"javascript: foo(value)">
```

So I've done the same in my jsx file:

```
<a href={javascript: ()=>foo(value)}>Click Here!</a>
```

but it doesn't work. 
How it can be done?

Comment: element.href = '#'; element.addEventListener('click', () => foo(value));

Comment: but I want the context menu behavior, and this way I don't get it

Comment: @Joe — What specific context menu behaviour are you looking for? Open Link In New Window generally won't work with JavaScript scheme URLs. Nor will Save Link As.

Comment: @Quentin - suppose i want to click on 'open link..' but block it from opening a new window and instead executing my method. is it possible?

Comment: @Joe — So you want something which isn't a link, but when people right click on it, you want to display a context menu that prompts them to "Open Link In New Window" which, if they click on it … **won't** open a new window? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Quentin - why? I have an <a> button that has an onclick which does lots of stuff and then redirect. Now they're asking me to have it open through a contextmenu, but I have these logics that I need

Comment: @Joe — Part of your problem is that you opened by asking [the wrong question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). `href="javascript:etc etc"` won't give you that result, so generating that with JavaScript won't help you.

Comment: You need to either use a real URL and server-side logic, or you need to use a `button` and [create a custom context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648292/right-click-menu-using-react-js)

Comment: I was aiming for a work around. Thanks anyway @Quentin

Answer (score 1):

## use reacts onClick

You can use `onClick` on an element in react.
like this

```
<a onClick={()=>foo(value)}>Click Here!</a>
```

That being said, if the purpose of your `a` tag is not to go to a link then your html is incorrect and you should think about using a `button` tag instead

Comment: That syntax won't compile and no such variable `javascript`

Comment: Joe I copied your code exactly, you had javaScript written in there for some reason, our good friend @Quentin sorted it out :)

Answer (score -1):

in React use onClick to do the job

```
<a onClick={() => doSomething("Hello") }>Click Me</a>
```